# Kong apis not enabled

Tags: kong

I have installed Kong (1.3.0rc2) in Ubuntu environment and using curl command I tried to get list of apis available but i am getting below error

`curl http://localhost:8001/apis/`.

`{"message":"Not found"}`

is there anything I missed to enable ? request for help.

Answer (score 1):

Please use http://localhost:8001/services/

instead of the earlier /apis